# How many ways can n persons, including Alice and Bob, sit in a row with exactly k persons between Alice and Bob?

Tags: combinatorics

My approach is to unite the group consisting of Alice ($A$), Bob ($B$) and $k$ persons between them into one new "person". 
So  we can permute $n-(k+2)$ and $k$ persons between $A$ and $B$ separately.

It seems like the answer should be $(n-(k+2))!\times k!$, but it is suspicious because it does not take into account two differnt cases for: $A$, k persons, $B$  or $B$, k persons, $A$. Overall I have no confidence in my approach.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider that people between A and B and people outside them are also interchangeable, so the answer can be simplified:

Consider A in the position $1$ of $n$. Now B is in the position $k+2$. There are $n-2$ anonymous people who can change positions, so in this configuration there are $(n-2)!$ possibilities. This reasoning can be done for each possible position of A, i.e. from position $1$ to position $n-k-1$ (A is before B for the moment). The only thing left is change the roles of A and B, so we should multiply by $2$.

So the final answer is $(n-2)! \cdot (n-k-1) \cdot 2 $

Edit: I'm considering there has to be exactly $k$ people between A and B, but they can be any $k$ people of all of them.

Comment: Ok, but look if you choose the position for $A$ at the first $k+1$ places then the position for $B$ will be exactly fixed. But if $A$ will be placed at the $k+2$ position and it will not be to close to the end, then there will be two possibilities for the $B$.

I think that the final answer will be $2\cdot(n-k-1)!\cdot k!$

Comment: Yes, there are two possibilities: one with A before B and one with B before A, that why I have multiplied by $2$.

Comment: Try for example the simple case n=4; k=0

Comment: Yes, I argree, it was my mistake. I understood your logic, but I can not agree with your statement : " There are $n−2$ anonymous people who can change positions" . I think there are two group, where positions should be mixed independently, i.e. people between $A$ and $B$ and the rest of people. How do you think?

Comment: Ok, I have gathered together your reasonings. Look, as you said the position for the $A$ can be chosen from the first $n-k-1$ positions. We have to encounter all possible permutations between $A$ and $B$ that will be exactly $k!$ possibilities and we have to count permutation for all the persons stayed outside the group. It will be $(n-(k+2))!$. Multiply all together and don't forget two:

$2\cdot (n-k-1)\cdot (n-(k+2))! \cdot k! = 2\cdot (n-k-1)!\cdot k!$.

Do you agree, @Javier ?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the problem. Let's consider 5 people: A,B,c,d,e (c, d, e being people whose order we don't care about). If we set k=1, we want the permutations in which there are exactly one person between A and B, but we don't care if it it c, d or e.
Say A is in the first place. I consider then the sequence A,c,B,d,e. If you only mix the c with the c you are not counting permutations like A,d,B,c,e.
That is what I mean when I say c,d,e are anonymous: they can change positions between all of them, not only their subset.

Comment: Of course, you can interpret "exactly k persons between A and B" as "there is a set of k given people which sits between A and B". In that case, you can't change the positions of people "inside" and "outside" A and B, and I agree your answer is then correct.

Comment: I would interpret the problem the same way you did.

Comment: @Javier , thank you a lot. you helped me come to the right answer. 
yes, you were exactly right. The final answer should be $2\cdot (n-k-1)!\cdot k! \cdot C^k_{n-2}$ which is the same as $2\cdot (n-k-1)(n-2)!$. The term $C_{n-2}^k = \frac{(n-2)!}{k!(n-k-2)!}$ denotes binomial coefficient, that makes difference - it shows that we choose $k$ persons among $n-2$ and then we make our permutations inside the groups. so your comment is taken into account.

Comment: @I.Voronov , glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is fine. But so is your suspicion. You can remedy that by multiplying with $2$ in the end. Apart from that, you made a little mistake: When replacing the $k+2$ persons with one new "person", you end up with $n-(k+2)+1$ persons.